# Combining function of array return type with structured binding declaration in C++17

Tags: c++, arrays, structured-bindings

I'm developing a system for an embedded application where performance is critical, but I also want well-structured code.
I want to combine arrays (not lists) structured binding declaration but I have some issues.
This is essentially what I want to do.

```cpp
uint8_t[] read_bytes(uint count) {
  // populate bytes by reading from serial connection
  // edit, used to be: static uint8_t[count] bytes;
  static uint8_t bytes[count];

  // ...

  return bytes;
}

void handle_instruction() {
  auto [ address, data, opcode ] = read_bytes(3);
}
```

But you can't return an array, you have to pass a pointer to that array, but then you can't unpack (or decompose) that in the handle_instruction function. I think I came to a solution with this

```cpp
template<uint N>
std::array<uint8_t, N> read_bytes() {
    std::array<uint8_t, N> bytes;

    // ...

    return bytes;
}

void handle_instruction() {
    auto [ address, data, opcode ] = read_bytes<3>();
}
```

Since capacity in a std::array has to be constant, I have to use templates to overcome this. But I feel like this approach is probably more complicated than necessary, is there anything else that could be a better solution to my problem?

Comment: `std::array` is the solution.  You can't return raw arrays from a function..  Your `uint8_t[]` return types is actually converted to `uint8_t*`

Comment: Seems like a reasonable solution to me.  You may want to use [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte).

Comment: `uint8_t[count] bytes` isn't valid c++ anyway, adding in `static` will probably make your code crash

Comment: `uint8_t bytes[count];` also isn't valid C++, it's trying to be a variable-length array and that's a C-only feature.